# A Conjecture based on the Complex Conjugate Root Theorem.

Tags: complex-analysis

The Complex Conjugate Root Theorem requires a polynomial function with real coefficients.  This seems to imply the possibility that a complex polynomial can exist with an odd number  of complex roots. True, or am I making  an assumption based on facts not in evidence?

Answer (score 11):

Hint: think about $z-i$  . . .

Comment: @Deusovi I assumed "complex roots" referred to complex *non-real* roots. (Note that $f(z)=z$ has only real coefficients.)

Comment: every monic polynomial f(z) is the product of $z-\alpha_k$, where $\alpha_k$ are its roots.

Comment: @DimaPasechnik Yes - so?

Comment: so you can get polynomials of degree n with n prescribed roots...

Comment: Well, you don't need that fact though - just look at $\prod (z-\alpha_k)$ for distinct $\alpha_k$s. We don't need to know that every monic has this form.

Comment: I agree, I was just thinking aloud